# How to set value in form validate for later validation functions

Tags: 7, forms

**Problem**

I'm adding the user register form onto the node create form with hook_form_alter.

The problem is the first step of account validation always fails because Drupal doesn't save Username to `form_state['values']['name']`. (I think because I'm combining two entity forms (user and node) and perhaps because it's not needed for the default entity node form?)

Either way I have 4 validation functions that run in $form['validate'];

```
0 (String, 18 characters ) node_form_validate | (Callback) node_form_validate();
1 (String, 39 characters ) commercecurrency_node_form_validate | (Callback) commercecurrency_job_advert_form_validate();
2 (String, 22 characters ) _editnode_validate | (Callback) editnode_validate();
3 (String, 26 characters ) user_account_form_validate | (Callback) user_account_form_validate();
```

I'm trying to set the value in `_editnode_validate` so `$form_state['values']['name']` is set when `user_account_form_validate` runs.

However the following code although it changes the value in `_editnode_validate`, doesn't save the value for the other validation functions. How can I get it to store the new value?

```
function _editnode_validate ($form, $form_state)

   $test_value = $form_state['input']['name'];
   $form_state['values']['name'] = $test_value;
```

(Both `_editnode_validate` and `user_account_form_validate` are added in `hook_form_alter`, and the code for `_editnode_validate` is in the `hook_form_alter` module.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is the problem just that your not passing $form_state by reference in your _editnode_validate validation function?

```
// note the & before $form_state to pass by reference
function _editnode_validate ($form, &$form_state) 

   $test_value = $form_state['input']['name'];
   $form_state['values']['name'] = $test_value;
```

Comment: Spot on, thanks for spotting that. I'm going to go hang my head in the drupal answers corner of shame.

Comment: Ha ha - so easy to miss these things - an extra pair of eyes always helps :)

Comment: @DominicWoodman Not trying to compound the shame but as this falls under the 'typo' category it's best to close it - unlikely to help future visitors and all that :)

Comment: @Clive Yep definitely, lets sweep this under the rug of shame so no-one else has to see it.